# Threading autocomplete SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, autocomplete

I need to thread a method due potential long loads from a database.  In this method it needs to check the SelectedItem of an autocomplete box.  I have figured out how update a textblock like this;

```
myCreditTotalTextBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    runningCreditTotalTextBlock.Text = "Loading"), 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
```

Although cannot figure out how to viewing the autocomplete SelectedItem.

thanks for the help

edit:
Thanks to @Sheridan this worked;

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Method(m));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but

> *You cannot access a UI element from a background thread*.

The `SelectedItem` of your `AutoCompleteBox` *is* a UI element, so you cannot access it from a background thread. Normally, we only run long running processes in background threads, so that the UI does not appear to freeze. If you have a long running process that requires information from the `SelectedItem` of your `AutoCompleteBox`, then just make a copy of it and pass *that*, or even just its property values instead.